# Why is my database migration not working and how I can fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

everyone. I'm trying to run a migration for my database (postgre) on Heroku, and when I run it, I get the following error:

PGError: ERROR:  column "morning_meds" cannot be cast to type "pg_catalog.bool"
: ALTER TABLE "users" ALTER COLUMN "morning_meds" TYPE boolean

The migration file in question has the following code:

```
class ChangeUserMedsFieldsToBoolean < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def down
    change_column :users, :morning_meds, :string
    change_column :users, :lunch_meds, :string
    change_column :users, :night_meds, :string
  end

  def up
    change_column :users, :morning_meds, :boolean
    change_column :users, :lunch_meds, :boolean
    change_column :users, :night_meds, :boolean
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how to fix the error or what could be causing the error, so any help you could give me would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure about the Rails specifics, but in PostgreSQL terms you need to use `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN col_name SET DATA TYPE boolean USING bool(col_name)`. The `USING` clause is key.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881750/how-to-convert-a-table-column-to-another-data-type

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11276990/398670

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Rails doesn't offer support for specifying a cast or transform function, which PostgreSQL requires for datatype changes where no implicit cast for that type pair exists.

You need to get Rails to execute:

```
ALTER TABLE users ALTER COLUMN col_name SET DATA TYPE morning_meds USING bool(col_name)
```

and since Rails apparently doesn't let you specify the `USING` clause via migrations, you need to do it manually. See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11276990/398670).

Alternately you could, pre-migration, run:

```
CREATE FUNCTION bool(text) RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
SELECT bool($1); 
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';

CREATE CAST (text AS boolean) WITH FUNCTION bool(text) AS IMPLICIT;
```

which will allow the ALTER to proceed without an explicit `USING` clause. You can and probably should drop the cast and bool(text) function after the migration:

```
DROP CAST (text AS boolean);
DROP FUNCTION bool(text);
```

Comment: You just have to wrap that SQL in a `connection.execute` call: `connection.execute('alter table ....')`. I end up doing that sort of thing all the time because I like CTEs, FKs, CHECKs, window functions, and other *exotic* things but Rails thinks databases are little more than spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I changed my :morning_meds migration to the following:    alter table users
    alter column :morning_meds type pg_catalog.bool using cast(:morning_meds as pg_catalog.bool)
The problem is that I'm now getting an error, which means my syntax is incorrect. Do you  mind helping me correct it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @user1483441 muistooshort nailed it; use connection.execute. I'm only commenting to make sure you get notified and see muistooshort's comment since you weren't @ mentioned

Comment: Okay great. Thanks very much! We ended up getting it working by clearing the db (we're only testing right now) and then migrating it again. Thank you so much for all of your help!